# Plotting solutions of coupled ODE with different boundary condition in one graph

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I use NDSolve to obtain solutions of three coupled ODEs. I have 10 solutions, sol1, sol2, ... , sol10, each one has a different boundary condition for one of the functions.

I can plot one of the solutions of one of the functions, A[x], as

Plot[Evaluate[{A[x]}/.sol1], {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel-> Automatic, PlotLegends -> {A1}]

How can I plot A[x] as obtained in sol1, sol2, ... , sol10, all in one plot? Namely so I can see how A[x] changes as I change this boundary condition.

Thank you!

Comment: What you need is something like (x^2) /. x -> {3, 4, 5}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of 3 solutions with 3 b.c for y[0]

```
s1 = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
   y, {x, 0, 30}];
s2 = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 2}, 
   y, {x, 0, 30}];
s3 = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 3}, y, {x, 0, 30}];
```

Here is how you plot them all. You can of course add plot labels too.

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. {s1, s2, s3}], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer to avoid a loop as suggested by @ChrisK.

```
soln[y0_?NumericQ] := First@NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == y0}, {y},
 {x, 0, 30}];

Plot[Evaluate[{y[x]} /. soln[#] & /@ Range[1, 4, 1]], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Black}]
```

[image]

You can also try `ParametricNDSolve` instead of `SetDelay`.

Answer (score 1):

@Lotus's answer is correct, but it could be tedious to enter the equations for 10 solutions.  Here's an automated, extensible version of their solution:

```
Do[
  s[i] = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == i}, y, {x, 0, 30}]
, {i, 10}];

Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. Table[s[i], {i, 10}]], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```